Probability density function in histogram (gnuplot)
I have been working on a histogram plot in gnuplot but I would like to also include a probability density distribution on top of the histogram itself. Currently I am able to produce the figure below but it seems the scale of the probability density function itself is completely off.
data from 'DZ_ref-CCSD_error' - https://pastebin.com/xX1MUd8i
Code attached:
reset
stats 'DZ_ref-CCSD_error' using 1
 n=STATS_records #number of intervals
 max=STATS_max #max value
 min=STATS_min #min value
 width=(max-min)/n #interval width
 binwidth=6
#+width/2.0 to center graph
 bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width) + width/2.0
 set term png
 set output "histogram_out.png"
 set xtics -100,50,100
 set boxwidth binwidth
 set mxtics 5
 set style fill solid 0.5 
 set tics out nomirror
 set tics font ", 12"
 set ytics 0,0.25,0.5
 set mytics 5
 set yrange [0:0.50]
 set xrange [-100:100]
 gauss(x)=a/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma)*exp(-(x-mean)**2/(2*sigma**2))
 fit gauss(x) 'DZ_ref-CCSD_error' via a, sigma, mean
 plot 'DZ_ref-CCSD_error' u (bin($1, binwidth)-0.5*binwidth):(1./n*binwidth) smooth fnormal w boxes lc           rgb     "green" notitle, \
  gauss(x) w lines ls 2 lw 2

histogram with incorrect probability density
If anyone could point out where my mistake is or add any insight on this issue it would be greatly appreciated!

The simple mistake is that you are trying to fit the raw data, but you actually need to fit the binned histogram data.
So, simple solution: write your histogram data into a datablock table, e.g. $Histo and fit the Gaussian to this data.
Check the following complete (a bit rewritten) example:
Data: SO79153881.dat
-26.426
-0.062
-2.207
-0.302
-2.128
-5.268
7.564
-5.959
0.016
1.069
5.012
-2.561
16.145
27.64
-0.049
-6.315
0.0597
0.047
122.326
0.354
0.003
122
3.016
1.122
0.001
0.172
0.906
-13.012
9.815
-9.193
-0.041
0.001
-10.143
-4.746
17.549
-26.467
-0.015
0.254
6.102
-3.09
12.202
-9.759
1.793
25.296
-2.096
1.751
0.35
2.916
-0.43
0.003
0.395
3.813
29.021
3.498
-5.013
0.401
0.89
1.543
-1.611
1.159
0.055
2.949
6.737
-5.935
0
-0.015
-7.406
0.471
1.45
2.37
-4.509
1.473
0.002
0.941
0.285
-0.029
1.607
-0.729
-20.279
19.272
2.189
0.0048
4.144
0.181
0.083
0.162
-2.71
1.699
0.084
0.524
0.19
-0.011
0.08
3.562
26.203
7.459
-6.999
1.833
2.926
3.28
2.247
30.148
-0.098
26.572
-15.62
-0.119
0.248
-0.235
-13.173
11.535
8.358
-0.855
2.007
-2.621
7.28
0.808
-0.484
28.104
-0.021
2.023
10.761
1.195
-1.966
9.326
0.006
1.137
0.268
0.303
-4.066
12.69
-0.013
0.019
0.579
1.675
-0.076
0.006
-8.134
-1.428
-0.854
0.408
-0.06
7.55
0.215
0.647
0.001
-0.358
-12.749
-0.009
-35.656
-4.529
-11.391
0.008
-0.012
-0.132
3.561
-22.863
6.031
4.271
-0.12
6.817
10.17
-0.089
61.425
1.538
0.045
-0.184
-15.299
0.195
0.039
-0.087
-6.891
0.002
0.475
-0.118
-0.977
-10.807
-0.066
-2.457
0.02
-0.002
4.929
-1.562
-0.016
0.826
-0.047
1.202
0.073
1.383
-0.245
-5.766
-0.002
1.34
0.223
-1.505
-0.737
-0.013
-0.012
-0.018
-0.006
-14.78
0.368
-0.434
3.16
8.424
0.132
1.64
-0.22
35.201
0.458
0.005
0.847
27.457
-0.032
0.029
0.216
11.494
-0.035
0.026
0.767
-3.385
-0.871
1.97
1.222

Script:
### fit gaussian to histogram
reset session

FILE = "SO79153881.dat"

stats FILE u 1
n        = STATS_records     # number of intervals
max      = STATS_max         # max value
min      = STATS_min         # min value
width    = (max-min)/n       # interval width
binwidth = 6
bin(x,width) = width*floor(x/width) + width/2.0

set xtics -100,50,100
set boxwidth binwidth
set mxtics 5
set style fill solid 0.5 
set tics out nomirror
set tics font ", 12"
set ytics 0,0.25,0.5
set mytics 5
set yrange [0:0.50]
set xrange [-100:100]
set samples 500

set table $Histo
     plot FILE u (bin($1, binwidth)-0.5*binwidth):(1./n*binwidth) smooth fnormal
unset table

gauss(x) = a/(sqrt(2*pi)*sigma)*exp(-(x-mean)**2/(2*sigma**2))
fit gauss(x) $Histo u 1:2 via a, sigma, mean

plot $Histo u 1:2 w boxes lc "green" notitle, \
     gauss(x) w lines ls 2 lw 2
### end of script

Result:


Thanks a lot! This was exactly what I was trying to do.

@JordeyJunks Glad to hear. So, if it answered your question, please check the checkmark on the top left of the answer, indicating that your problem was solved. On StackOverflow: upvote="was helpful" and accept = "solved the problem".
